# Iteration in Parsing Script: Value remains the same

Tags: python, regex

I am currently developing a parser that iterates over .txt files containing transcripts of earnings conference calls. The objective is to extract sections spoken by a CEO. The provided code snippet is part of a larger script responsible for extracting various pieces of information, such as the date of the call and the company. You can find the complete transcript incl. the regex here: https://regex101.com/r/mhKevB/1

```
    presentation_part = """
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Inge G. Thulin,  3M Company - Chairman, CEO & President    [3]
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

          Thank you, Bruce, and good morning, everyone. Coming off a strong 2017, our team opened the new year with broad-based organic growth across all business groups. We expanded margins and posted a double-digit increase in earnings per share while continuing to invest in our business and return cash to our shareholders.
"""

ceos_lname_clean = ['Thulin', 'Davis']


try:
    ceos_speaches_pres = []
    if len(ceos_lname_clean) != 0: 
        for lname in ceos_lname_clean:
            ceo_pattern = fr'(?m){lname}.*?(?:CEO|Chief Executive Officer)\b(?:(?!\n-+$).)*?\[\d+\]\s+^-+\s+((?s:.*?))(?=\s+^-+|\Z)' #Alternatives pattern wo neben dem Begriff CEO auch auf den Namen des CEO gematched wird
            ceo_textparts_pres = re.findall(ceo_pattern, presentation_part, re.DOTALL | re.IGNORECASE)
            ceo_speech_presentation = " ".join(ceo_textparts_pres)
            ceos_speaches_pres.append(ceo_speech_presentation)
        #Overall_dict[folder][comp_path]["CEO Presentation Speech"] = ceos_speaches_pres ##Add the text to a dict

    else: ##try for COO in case ceos_lname_clean is empty
        coos_speaches_pres = [] 
        for coo_lname in coos_lname_clean:
            coo_pattern = fr'(?m){coo_lname}.*?(?:COO|Chief Operating Officer)\b(?:(?!\n-+$).)*?\[\d+\]\s+^-+\s+((?s:.*?))(?=\s+^-+|\Z)' #Alternatives pattern wo neben dem Begriff COO auch auf den Namen des COO gematched wird
            coo_textparts_pres = re.findall(coo_pattern, presentation_part, re.DOTALL | re.IGNORECASE)
            coo_speech_presentation = " ".join(coo_textparts_pres)
            coos_speaches_pres.append(coo_speech_presentation)
        #Overall_dict[folder][comp_path]["COO Presentation Speech"] = coos_speaches_pres ##Add the text to a dict
except:
    print("PROBLEM")
```

The provided snippet successfully extracts the text spoken by Thulin. However, when integrated into the overall script, an issue arises: ceo_textparts_pres retains the value of the previous iteration. That is, even ceo_textparts_pres for Davis should remain empty it holds the text spoken by Thulin.

I have spent the entire day troubleshooting this problem without success and keep getting more and more frustrated. The entire script is unfortunately too extensive to post it here but even the smallest hint or suggestions what might cause this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance for your assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex pattern between the last name `{lname}` and the rank part `(CEO|Ch.Ex.Of.)`,

Namely `.*?` matches multiple lines because of the `re.DOTALL` flag. leading both Davis and Thulin to be matched from the introduction section.
I recommend not using re.DOTALL flag for the entire pattern and turning it on for a specific section using `(?s:.*)` or just matching newlines explicitly like this: `(?:\n|.)*`.

To demonstrate i added a test case below with two patterns. The commented out line has DOTALL disabled for that section using `(?-e:.*?)` instead of `.*?`. and does not match the bad case.

```py
import re

presentation_part = """
today Davis
met miss Thulin
they were both CEO
on day number [3]
- bad case"""

ceos_lname_clean = ["Thulin", "Davis"]


ceos_speaches_pres = []
for lname in ceos_lname_clean:
    ceo_pattern = rf"(?m){lname}.*?(?:CEO|Chief Executive Officer)\b(?:(?!\n-+$).)*?\[\d+\]\s+^-+\s+((?s:.*?))(?=\s+^-+|\Z)"
    # ceo_pattern = rf"(?m){lname}(?-s:.*?)(?:CEO|Chief Executive Officer)\b(?:(?!\n-+$).)*?\[\d+\]\s+^-+\s+((?s:.*?))(?=\s+^-+|\Z)"
    ceo_textparts_pres = re.findall(
        ceo_pattern, presentation_part, re.DOTALL | re.IGNORECASE
    )
    ceo_speech_presentation = " ".join(ceo_textparts_pres)
    ceos_speaches_pres.append(ceo_speech_presentation)

print(ceos_speaches_pres)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I would have never thought of that